# How to create pairs from two arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
        $q = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE partner='$qpartner' AND group_id='$gi' AND status='1'";
        $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
                $usinneed[] = $row[0];
            }
        $affected = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);
        $q2 = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE partner<>'$qpartner' AND group_id='$gi' AND status='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $affected";
        $r2 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q2) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2)) {
                $potent_partners[] = $row[0];
            }

            $current = end($usinneed);
            $partners = array();
            foreach ($usinneed as $user)
            {
                $partners[$user] = $current;
                $current = $user;
                $q = "UPDATE users SET partner = '{$partners[$user]}' WHERE user_id = '{$user}'";
                mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
            }

        print_r($partners);
```

I'm lost as soon as I come to the $current; that's where the changes are needed and I need help.
$usinneed is an array of all of the users who need a partner, and $potent_partners is an array of potential partners to pair with the Users In Need ($usinneed).
The arrays have an equal number of rows.  How do I update the users table so that each $usinneed has their partner field set to one of the $potent_partners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) be of any help perhaps?

**EDIT**

Given the comments below, here's the new details (formatted correctly):

We start with the queries that populate two arrays: `$usersInNeed` (an array of those *without partners*) and `$newPartners` (an array of people that need to be paired up with `$usersInNeed`)

We pair them up in PHP using [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). So

```
$usersInNeed = Array(2,4); // Keys
$newPartners = Array(8,5); // values
$combined = array_combine($usersInNeed,$newPartners); // result: Array(2 => 8, 4 => 5);
```

Now, we go back through the database and update those users with their partner. You can do this a bunch of ways, but a foreach seems simplest:

```
// take each entry in $combined and break it out so the key is "$userInNeed" and the
// value is "$newPartner" (illustrate what array_combine did)
foreach ($combined as $userInNeed => $newPartner) 
{
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET partner='{$newPartner}' WHERE user_id='{$userInNeed}';";
  // execute the statement
}
```

Comment: The users table contains two relevant fields: `user_id` and `partner`.  The first array I pull consists of user_ids, specifically the ids of people who need a new partner.  The second array is the list of partners I wish to assign.  Potentially that could look like: usersinneed: (2,4); and newpartners: (8,5).  I need to populate 2 & 4's `partner` field with the values 8 & 5, respectively.

Comment: @David: So if I'm concluding correctly, `$partners = array_merge($partners,array_combine($usersinneed,$newpartners));` should work for your purpose.

Comment: I ended up with: `$c = array_combine($usinneed, $npartners);`  However, I need to know how to format the query after combining the arrays.  The following doesn't work: `$q = "UPDATE users SET partner = '{$c[$npartners]}' WHERE user_id = '{$usinneed}'";`  If I need to be using foreach, I'm not at the moment because I don't know how to write that either.

Comment: @David: What's the query you're going for? Use "english" translation instead of code, e.g. "for every entry in $parters query ....".

Comment: For every user_id in the combined-array, I want the table updated so that partner column is equal to the npartners value in the combined array.  So, if the combined array looks like: `Array ( [2] => 5 [4] => 3 )`, then I want user 2 to have 5 as his partner, and user 4 to have 3 as his partner.

Comment: @David: `foreach ($c as $user => $partner) { $sql = "UPDATE users SET partner='{$partner}' WHERE user_id='{$user}';"; /* execute query */ }`

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much.  I'm obviously new at this, and I learn so much better through examples.  That foreach stuff had me confused, and you cleared it up.

Comment: @David: Not a problem, we all learned some time. ;-) You can also do all of this in the very comfort of SQL (not have to extract it to push an update again) but I just assume not get too elaborate. ;-)

Comment: Well, if your up for it, I'd love to see that.

Comment: @David: Can-do, just what is `$qpartner`? From what I see, you should always have an even number of users in the table and you're basically switching people off (almost like a sports bracket or something). Unless the code you originally posted is in a loop that makes $qpartner change, I only see one possible row come back. Then again, you could allow people to share partners?

Comment: Think of it more like a gift exchange. Each user has another user as his partner, but, while each user knows who his partner is, nobody knows to whom he is partnered. A gives to B anonymously, B gives to C anonymously, and so on, until L gives to A anonymously. But, when somebody quits the exchange program, whomever he was partnered to now needs a new partner. So, when C quits, then B needs a new partner. For my own purposes, I don't want to just give C's old partner, D, to be B's new partner. That's why I'm selecting all potentials and randomly assigning them as new partners to those in need.

Comment: @David: So is that where the status column comes in to play? What flags the user as "out", you essentially look in the users table for any rows that have a partner that's been flagged or physically removed?

Comment: In plain English, when user-C quits, 1) I check that the user was actually in play, 2) I mark that user as inactive, 3) then I find everyone who had him as their partner, 3.1) Everyone who had him as their partner needs a new partner assigned, so I randomly select as many active people as had him as their partner when he quit, excluding those who had him as partner, and 3.2) then I assign the partnerships.

Answer (score 0):

you do like this:

foreach ($usinneed as $user)
{
      foreach($potent_partners as $partners)
       {
                  your sql code inside
                   now u have $partners[$user]
       }

}

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested, but maybe you can do something like this instead.

```
$query = 'UPDATE users SET users.partner = (SELECT partners.user_id FROM users AS partners WHERE partners.user_id != users.user_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) WHERE 1';
```

are two different users allowed to have the same partner?
does each user's partner also have to then have that user as their partner?
what happens if there are not enough available partners? users?